# facebook share image not work for user's facebook profile picture url only (ios)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-share

I am using Facebook sharing in my iOS App. and I want to share my logged in user's profile picture. but the user logged in to my app using facebook, thus I have user's profile picture link is as follows,

**http://graph.facebook.com/< FBID >/picture?type=large**

but unfortunately I can not share the image as i am getting and error 1500 from facebook. Although I can share image from other servers.

Does anyone have idea about this?

Comment: That URL redirects to Facebook’s CDN, and Facebook doesn’t allow images on their CDN to be used f.e. as the thumbnail image of Open Graph objects. Possible that you can not share them directly as well.

Comment: is there any solution for that? or does facebook has mentioned it anywhere in their docs?

Comment: If that’s the cause (do you get any more information with that 1500 error you mentioned?), then you can only proxy the profile pictures through another script first.

Comment: no I do not get more information about that error